# In socket io, one user connection creates dozens of "joining room"?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a nodejs socket.io application on linux connected to clients running socket-io-client.

The nosejs server is:

- node v6.7.0
- express 4.10.8
- socket.io 1.4.5

the java side is using maven:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>io.socket</groupId>
     <artifactId>socket.io-client</artifactId>
     <version>0.8.3</version>
  </dependency>
```

I am just migrating from socket.io 0.9, so I have only one user connect to the nodejs socket server.

In some of the cases I have a weird phenomenon were this one connection creates dozens of connections

```
socket.io:socket socket connected - writing packet +106ms
socket.io:socket joining room /#q-brvq0-lMhLKY6tAAAR +0ms
socket.io:socket joined room /#q-brvq0-lMhLKY6tAAAR +0ms
socket.io:socket socket connected - writing packet +46ms
socket.io:socket joining room /#p-_dEpC_2IJoiVtFAAAS +0ms
socket.io:socket joined room /#p-_dEpC_2IJoiVtFAAAS +0ms
socket.io:socket socket connected - writing packet +4ms
socket.io:socket joining room /#9Ha8CuQh6Vw3OROuAAAT +0ms
socket.io:socket joined room /#9Ha8CuQh6Vw3OROuAAAT +0ms
socket.io:socket socket connected - writing packet +192ms
socket.io:socket joining room /#qu1Hhixulei3fDV7AAAU +0ms
socket.io:socket joined room /#qu1Hhixulei3fDV7AAAU +0ms
socket.io:socket socket connected - writing packet +24ms
socket.io:socket joining room /#0Jd2FY5rY-_Rfps6AAAV +0ms
socket.io:socket joined room /#0Jd2FY5rY-_Rfps6AAAV +0ms
socket.io:socket socket connected - writing packet +122ms
socket.io:socket joining room /#BCgabXA28IBHV94NAAAW +0ms
socket.io:socket joined room /#BCgabXA28IBHV94NAAAW +0ms
socket.io:socket socket connected - writing packet +19ms
socket.io:socket joining room /#ibtuQc60nb7kExHvAAAX +1ms
```

From the java client this is the code that creates the connection:

```
        try {
             System.out.println("socket phy create");
            socket = IO.socket(domain+":"+port);
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            System.out.println("socket URISyntaxException");
        }
```

95% of the times it creates only one "socket connect", and the 5% it creates dozens. What is the problem or can you suggest a way to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the system implementation..

While I was debugging, I sometimes was closing the socket server (in order to change some code). On the client side, I have a reconnection check every 5 seconds. This method called the createNodeConnection every time. When finally I reloaded the socket server, all these connections connected at once.

The fix was to separate the 'socket creation' from the 'socket connection' (and use the 'socket connection' in the reconnection method)

```
public void createNodeConnection() {
        try {
            socket = IO.socket(domain+":"+port);
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            System.out.println("socket URISyntaxException");
        }

        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
          @Override
          public void call(Object... args) {...//handle code..}

        }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

          @Override
          public void call(Object... args) {...//handle code..}

        }).on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {...//handle code..};
        });            

        socketConnection();
};


public void socketConnection() {
         socket.connect();            

}
```